# How can I generate html and text emails from the same source?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, premailer

I'm sending html emails using [premailer](https://github.com/fphilipe/premailer-rails3). By default, it will generate a simple text rendering of the email based on the non-html content. It's an okay start, but has some annoyances such as literal rendering of all breaks.

Is there a way for me to have a little more control over the text rendering of the email, either with premailer or another tool?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out [MarkerB](https://github.com/plataformatec/markerb)

It lets you write your mailer template in Markdown, and it auto-makes html and text versions of your email for sending as multipart mime.